# Multiple keystrokes as autohotkey shortcut

Tags: autohotkey

I'm new to AutoHotkey.
I have a specfic need to be achieved in Powerpoint using autohotkey.

Let's say in Powerpoint, I want to change font color.
The normal steps are:

1. Select the text
2. Click "Home" > Click "Font Color" > The Font palette gets expanded and I select the color.

Now, I want to make this process quicker as below

1. Select the text
2. Press FC (as shortcut from keyboard) and autohotkey should press the following keys Alt+H+FC (Very importantly, if I don't press C immediately after F, then it should get typed as replaced text of highlighted text)

So, my code goes as like this

```
#SingleInstance, Force
#IfWinActive ahk_exe POWERPNT.EXE ; check whether ppt is the active window 
f::  
#if keypress c
    send, !HFC
#if 
return
```

But, this doesn't work.
I don't where am I making mistake. Could someone help, please

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an autohotkey question, but the quick access toolbar (QAT) in PowerPoint may solve your problem out of the box.

The QAT assigns Alt+1 to the first feature, alt+2 to the second, etc. By customizing the order of buttons on the QAT, you can access features you use often with one key combination.

**Instructions**
First add the font color button to the QAT: right click the 'font color' button, and click 'add to quick access toolbar'
[image: Context menu for change font color]

Change the order of features in the QAT: right click on the QAT - customize quick access toolbar). Use the arrow buttons on the right side to change the ordering.
This is the order I use myself:
[image: Example buttons on quick access toolbar]

This allows me to very quickly align objects on a slide, change background color, outline, and text color, all initiated from the keyboard.

Comment: Thank you, solves the purpose to an extent, but I'm looking for keyboard shortcuts as like alphabets

Answer (score 0):

Changing `send, !HFC` to `send, !hfc` should do the trick.

There's a difference between sending capital letters or normal ones for PowerPoint.

Actually, I'd recommend a different trigger than typing a single letter. I used win+Q in the example below

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class PPTFrameClass
#q::
    Send !hfc
return
```